# PHP: why does this image fail to download?

Tags: php, curl, download, imagedownload

Using PHP I'm trying to download/save the following image:

```
http://www.bobshop.nl/catalog/product_image.php?size=detail&id=42428
```

When you load this image in a browser, you can see it, but when I try to download it using several different methods, I get an 1 KB file that says that the product could not be found on the server.

I tried this with both the `file_put_contents` and the `curl` way.
I even used the function `get_web_page` that I found somewhere on StackOverflow, to catch a possible redirect.

What else could be the reason that you can see the image in a browser, but no way to download it ?

***UPDATE:***
Thanks to an error that was thrown trying out the different answers, I just found out the real cause of the problem.  Somewhere in the process of scraping the html, the URL got `&amp;` instead of `&` . I replace these now and every other method works now too...  thanks all!

Comment: There's probably some header checking to verify that the requester is actually a browser. Why not try requesting the image with Google Chrome and opening up the inspector? Go to the network tab. Refresh the page. Copy the sent headers and use those with cURL.

Comment: I guess they have protections in place against downloading, possibly by checking the User Agent string

Comment: You could even take it a step further and play around with the headers and see which combination returns the image and which returns the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented a simple way to download and store and it worked:

```
<?php

$fileContent = implode("",file("http://www.bobshop.nl/catalog/product_image.php?size=detail&id=42428"));
$fp = fopen("/tmp/image","w+");

fwrite($fp, $fileContent);

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Are you behind a proxy? This could be the problem (you are with proxy configured but php not) ;)

Comment: I accept this as answer, since trying out your code directed me to the real cause :  &amp;  instead of & in the URL!

Answer (score 0):

There is likely some kind of header checking that is being done with this PHP script to ensure that a browser is requesting the image and not someone trying to scrape their content. This can be forged (although after doing something like this I feel like I need to take a shower) with cURL. Specifically, [`curl_setopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-agent: Some legitimate string'
));
```

To find out which headers need to be sent, you'll need to do some experimentation. If you have Google Chrome, you've probably used the Inspector (If you don't Firefox has similar addons, so you can use something like Firebug). If you request the image with Chrome, you can right click to inspect it. Go to the Network tab. Now refresh the page. The request to `product_image.php` should show up. If you click on it and click the Headers tab, you should see a list of headers sent. My browsers sends: `User-Agent`, `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept-Language`, and `Accept-Charset`.

[image]

Try combinations of these headers with valid values to see which ones need to be sent for the image to be returned. I'd bet that this site probably only checks `User-agent` so **start with that one.**

---

**An important note:** You should cache the result of this call, because it will be very suspicious if your server requests the image multiple times in rapid succession (say if many users on your site request the script that grabs this image). Also as an extra layer of anonymity, you might want to pick your `User-agent` from an array of valid ones so bobshop.nl thinks that all of the requests are coming from users behind a large network (like a college campus). You can find valid user agent strings on [UserAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. The problem wasn't complicated at all, see UPDATE.